# Issue with oddly shaded faces in Blender 2.82

Tags: shaders, edges, faces

Hi everyone and happy new year.

Recently I have encountered a problem with some models in Blender (I use 2.82). When importing a model I have made in Sketchup, Blender "creates" these weird dark grey shapes on the model itself. I have gone back and forth between Blender and Sketchup to fix this - but nothing solves this. Please see the attached screenshots - I have circled the issues in red. There are no vertices or edges close to the problem areas.

What I have tried thus far:

- Checked normals and ensured they are facing the right way.
- Tried to add edges to the problem area.
- Subdivided the model (makes it worse).
- Tried various shading settings.
- Tried exporting from Sketchup in various formats.
- Tried importing the various formats of the model with various import settings.
- Removing materials and reassigning them.
- Cleaning up the mesh.

The problem persists even when I load it into Substance Painter to texture it...the rest of the model is fine, except for those annoying dark areas. Can anyone advise on what this is and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

[image: Problem Areas]

[image: Problem Areas in Edit Mode]

Comment: Given everything you've already tried, it's hard to tell without seeing your project. Any chance you could upload and post an example of your .blend file so we can have a look at it? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - thank you for answering...here it is: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=v1G9Ro51" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/v1G9Ro51/)

Comment: Ok, so I can definitely say what is going on is topology related, but I can't tell you how to fix it because there's a lot going on. To get an idea, grab the inner edge of the bottom windowsill(s) and move it around. You can see it's connected to the rest of the mesh in a large number of places, but are not properly connected via "vertex junctions". For example, some lines go straight past another edge, but there is no vertex to connect them - they are just "infinitely beside each other" Have a look at the linked image for an example - https://ibb.co/Q9dFRSy

Answer (score 1):

After going crazy with button-pressing, I finally solved it. Under the Object Data Properties tab, I selected "clear custom split normals data" and voila! No idea why the model imported with that...but at least this was one issue that was solved by pressing random buttons! Thanks to everyone that viewed/was willing to help.

[image]

Comment: it's sometimes necessary to clear the custom split normals of imported meshes